# Motivation of having Functional Dependencies

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies

What is the motivation of having functional dependencies in Haskell ?

One example of a functional dependency:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadSupply s m | m -> s where
  next :: m (Maybe s)
```

It is stated in the RWH book, that functional dependency helps the type checker. How does it actually help ?

Also, this piece of code actually compiles:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadSupply s m where
      next :: m (Maybe s)
```

But I guess, it will produce an runtime error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to write code not using functional dependencies, it's just a pain to use since the inference sucks.

Basically without FDs, the function `get :: MonadState m s => m s` will have to figure out `m` and `s` independently. Usually `m` is quite easily inferred, but often `s` would require an explicit annotation.

Moreover, this is much more general than we need, so instead we can restrict our typechecker to say "For `m`, there is exactly 1 `s`", this way, once `m` is inferred, `s` is obvious to the type inference algorithm

Comment: I cannot understand how `For m, there is exactly 1 s`. If we tell, for `m` there is exactly one `s`, then why not write them as `MonadSupply m m` ? (I know that I'm sounding crazy :) )

Comment: @Sibi Because `s` is usually different, for example with `MonadState`, we have `StateT s` and `s`, clearly for all `StateT s` we really just want to use `s`.

Comment: Any given "supply monad" will typically only supply one type!  For example if you have `m = MySpecialSupplyMonad s` that supplies values of type `s` then you know from the type "`MySpecialSupplyMonad s`" the supply type by just reading the type argument "`s`".  Thus `s` can be said to functionally depend on `m`.

Comment: I think the type signature should look like this: `get :: MonadState s m => m s` ?

Comment: @jozefg, thanks for your effort. But I'm still not able to grasp it. I have asked a new followup question.

Comment: sounds more like a Sigma type rather than a (functionally) dependent type. (the difference being that (functionally) dependent type finds a type B for any type A; whereas Sigma is a evidence of existence of B for some A)